# Cannot login into Gnome desktop except with root-user

Tags: gnome, login, gui

I'm not able to connect with a non-root user to the gui gnome destop envronment. Over console, like ssh login is possible.
Temporary I changed limits file `* hard    as              51200` but comment it out later.
I reinstalled:

- gnome-session
- gdm service
- glibs

I'm getting following error from the cockpit panel:

```
7:56 AM
Failed to start GNOME Shell on Wayland.
systemd
7:56 AM
org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
systemd
7:56 AM
Failed to create backend: Could not get session ID: Couldn't get type for session '35': No such device or address
gnome-shell
7:56 AM
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
org.gnome.Shell.desktop
7:56 AM
>                   X11 cannot support keycodes above 255.
org.gnome.Shell.desktop
7:56 AM
> Warning:          Unsupported maximum keycode 708, clipping.
org.gnome.Shell.desktop
7:56 AM
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
org.gnome.Shell.desktop
7:56 AM
Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
systemd
7:56 AM
app-gnome-xdg\x2duser\x2ddirs-33433.scope: Failed with result 'resources'.
systemd
7:56 AM
app-gnome-xdg\x2duser\x2ddirs-33433.scope: Failed to add PIDs to scope's control group: No such process
systemd
7:56 AM
Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
systemd
7:56 AM
app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dsecrets-33431.scope: Failed with result 'resources'.
systemd
7:56 AM
app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dsecrets-33431.scope: Failed to add PIDs to scope's control group: No such process
systemd
7:56 AM
Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
systemd
7:56 AM
app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dpkcs11-33428.scope: Failed with result 'resources'.
systemd
7:56 AM
app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dpkcs11-33428.scope: Failed to add PIDs to scope's control group: No such process
systemd
7:56 AM
WARNING: Failed to start app: Unable to start application: Failed to fork (Resource temporarily unavailable)
gnome-session-binary
7:56 AM
WARNING: Could not get session id for session. Check that logind is properly installed and pam_systemd is getting used at login.
gnome-session-binary
7:56 AM
gnome-session-monitor.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
systemd
7:56 AM
gnome-session-monitor.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=5/TRAP
systemd
7:56 AM
Failed to start GNOME Initial Setup Copy Worker.
systemd
7:56 AM
gnome-initial-setup-copy-worker.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
systemd
7:56 AM
gnome-initial-setup-copy-worker.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=5/TRAP
systemd
7:56 AM
Process 33403 (gnome-session-c) of user 1000 dumped core.
systemd-coredump
7:56 AM
Process 33402 (gnome-initial-s) of user 1000 dumped core.
systemd-coredump
7:56 AM
creating thread 'gmain': Error creating thread: Resource temporarily unavailable
gnome-session-c
7:56 AM
creating thread 'gmain': Error creating thread: Resource temporarily unavailable
gnome-initial-s
7:56 AM
gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
```

It seems to a have no access to gmain as non-root user anymore. But could not locate the source of this thread.

Selinux is permissive.